# 64-bit Assembler development environment?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, masm, tasm

Looking for something similar to the old Borland TASM/TLINK for complete beginners to use.  I don't like MASM in Visual Studio.  I just want to knock up some very small routines in Notepad++ or similar, then assemble and link them.  There are lots of assemblers around but I have still to find a linker that works.  At the moment we are using the virtual environment on Tutorials Point, but it's really aimed at Linux and we are building for 64-bit Windows.  All suggestions greatfully recieved!

Comment: I changed the tag. Check that you really meant x86-64 and not the ancient 8086.

Comment: However, I realized that software recommendations are off-topic here. Check http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: If you want a simple editor that works with a few different assemblers (and generates 64 and 32-bit), you might want to consider looking at the [Simple Assembler(SASM)](https://dman95.github.io/SASM/english.html). It is a simple editor with backend support for NASM,GNU assembler(GAS), and FASM. Each one of these assemblers is included in the installation. It also supports MASM as a back end, but MASM has to be installed manually and set up properly in the settings.

Answer (score 2):

NASM is probably a good bet. I get the impression that it is popular in the linux world, and there is a windows version. I have only used it under linux, and not much at all really so I can't recommend a linker for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at [yasm](http://yasm.tortall.net) that is a modern replacement of NASM